# Hang in poll system call

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace, lsof

My program intermittently hanging in the poll call

*strace output*

```
poll([{fd=52, events=POLLIN}], 1, 250 <unfinished ...>
<... poll resumed> ) = 0 (Timeout) <0.250281>
wait4(16953, 0x7f00cd24d90c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0 <0.000019>
```

Looks like it is waiting on POLLIN(POLLIN-no data to read) event. From the lsof output I found the file, the file is text file. But not sure what is causing the hang in poll call

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: hi, did you understand how to fix the problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it seems the application process was stuck in POLLIN event but actual hang was in other event where my application process waiting for other process to respond.